# FreeBSD 9 KDE4 No Mouse or keyboard at KDE login screen

Tags: xorg, kde, xinput

Fresh Install of FreeBSD 9 and KDE 4. System boots to KDE log in screen, but no mouse or keyboard when I get there. I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> out of the KDE.

I Have the following lines in rc.conf:

```
moused_port="/dev/psm0"
moused_type="auto"
moused_enable"YES"
Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
local_startup="$(local_start_up) /usr/local/kde4/etc/rc.d"
hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
kdm_enable="YES"
```

Answer (score 2):

This line,

```
Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
```

is certainly not meant for `rc.conf` but for `xorg.conf` (from `man xorg.conf`):

> `Option "AutoAddDevices" "boolean"`
>
> If this option is disabled, then no devices will be added from the HAL or udev backends. Enabled by default.

Just try to add it there (to the `ServerLayout` or `ServerFlags` section, see [the documentation on *X11 Configuration*](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-config.html)).

I'm a little surprised you got KDM started at all, I'd have expected things *below* the line-not-meant-for-`rc.conf` to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue some minutes ago. After many unsuccessful queries using search engines, I checked the log to try to understand why those input methods weren't working.

In my case, installing the following 2 ports solved. I hope that it can help you out.

```
cd /usr/ports/x11-drivers/xf86-input-keyboard && sudo make install clean
cd /usr/ports/x11-drivers/xf86-input-mouse && sudo make install clean
```

After installing those, I rebooted my FreeBSD box and was able to get through the gdm login window.

[ PS: same answer as given in https://superuser.com/a/582666/192509, since it is a similar issue from my point of view. ]

Comment: I had to use `make reinstall` because the same version was already installed(but badly).