# Mouse and keyboard not working in FreeBSD 9.0

Tags: x11, freebsd, keyboard, xinput

Could not use keyboard and mouse at KDM log in screen in FreeBSD 9.0 KDE
Typed on nano:

```
hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
local_startup=${local_startup} /usr/local/kde4/etc/rc.d"
kdm4_enable="YES"
```

after saving I reboot and  log in screen appears but mouse and keyboard not enabled.

Comment: Have you installed the mouse and keyboard drivers for xorg?

Comment: Is it USB or PS2? If USB you might want to try a PS2 keyboard and mouse. It won't solve the problem, but will help you moving around quicker to solve the USB problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add AllowEmptyInput to your xorg.conf?

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same issue some minutes ago. After many unsuccessful queries using search engines, I checked the log to try to understand why those input methods weren't working.

In my case, installing the following 2 ports solved. I hope that it can help you out.

```
cd /usr/ports/x11-drivers/xf86-input-keyboard && sudo make install clean
cd /usr/ports/x11-drivers/xf86-input-mouse && sudo make install clean
```

After installing those, I rebooted my FreeBSD box and was able to get through the gdm login window.

[ PS: same answer as given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72402/37151, since it is a similar issue from my point of view. ]